# How to get the last word in the last line in a file with Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `sample.txt` with the content as below.

```
H|20170331|CIS
A||A1140|GRM  //header
A||A1140|GRM
A||A1140|GRM
A||A1140|GRM
A||A1140|GRM
T|20170331|5  //trailer
```

I need the last token in the last line i.e. `5`. *(It's the count of the line except header trailer)*.

As of now, I tried below; it's giving the first token, i.e. `T`, but I need the last token i.e. `5`.

```
@echo off
rem for /f "skip=1 tokens=2,* delims=" %%a in (sample.txt) do set "variable=%%a"

rem for /f "delims=|" %%x in (sample.txt) do set "variable=%%x"
for /f "delims=|" %%G in (sample.txt) do set "variable=%%G"
echo %variable%

pause
```

Note the file can contain thousands of records so the last token is required.

Comment: Have the last line 3 tokens _always_? If so, the solution is simple: `for /f "tokens=3 delims=|" %%G in (sample.txt) do set "variable=%%G"`

Comment: You need to be more specific about your file content, does the last line really have a trailing '  //trailer' because I'd assume if that were true '  //header' would be trailing on the first line, beginning `H|`, not the second. Also are there spaces in the fields/tokens on the trailer line and if so are those fields double quoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you want to get rid of the `//trailer` add a space as delimiter.

```
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=3delims=| " %%A in (sample.txt) Do Set LastRowCol3=%%A
Echo [LastRowCol3=%LastRowCol3%]
```