# batch to isulate last item in a text file with muliple item

Tags: windows, batch-file

for kindness I have a myTextFile.txt that contain something like this:

```
"C0001.MXF"
"C0002.MXF"
"C0003.MXF"
... 
"C0020.MXF"
```

I would like do a batch that echo only the last item, in this case C0020.mxf

Possibly I need to put the result in 2 variables:
one called var1 = "C0020.MXF"
and another call var2 = C0020.MXF (the same of var1 without the "")

How can I do? thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277485/how-to-get-the-last-word-in-the-last-line-in-a-file-with-windows-batch-script

Comment: thanks but honestly I cannot integrate it to my case

Comment: ok got that. first you have to remove the quotes and than extract the word. but tell us what you've tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: sorry but I'm not able to do nothing of this :(

Comment: I think is necessary the "for" command, but I cannot do that

Comment: for /f "delims="" [?] %%x in (myTextFile.txt) do (echo ??)

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f %%a in (mytextfile.txt) do set var=%%~a
echo %var%
```

derived from any of hundreds of similar solutions.

Since you claim this doesn't work, then the only conclusion I can draw is that the file is a single line, not a series of lines as proposed.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (mytextfile.txt) do for %%b in (%%a) do set var=%%~b
echo %var%
```

Comment: thank you but I don't know exactly why I get the first (C0001.MXF) instead of C0020.MXF

Comment: sorry but this don't seems to work. I need that the batch return the last token: C0020.MXF

Comment: @CamilloGatto Are you saving the text in a batchfile? It must work. Open CMD and paste this line in it (make sure that you add the full path to mytextfile.txt) `for /f %a in (C:\path\mytextfile.txt) do set var=%~a & echo %var%` It must display the last line in that file. If that then works you are doing something wrong with Magoo's answer.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: the command line in your comment won't work (no delayed expansion of `%var%`) Make it two lines instead of `&`.